# Maven: The type cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: maven, maven-3

I changed some existing projects from ant to maven projects.
So far so good.

All projects do have the same groupId.
Theres a project with name "ServerBase" and artifactId "server-base".
Within this project theres an abstract class "BaseService" which defines a logger via:

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
[...]
protected Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

Theres another project with name "Server" and artifactId "server".
Within this project theres a class ConfigurationDAOImpl extending the BaseService-Class above.
Within ConfigurationDAOImpl the logger log is used for creating some outputs.

Within the "Server"'s POM file I have declared:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tcom.amadeus</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-base</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Under BuildPath the dependency is shown very nice under MavenDependencies. I removed the old dirct/natural/ant-dependency from build path before.
If I remove it I am getting very much errors about missing classes etc.
But although I do have this dependency I am getting the followin error in eclipse (under tab markers):

```
The type org.apache.commons.logging.Log cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Resource: ConfigurationDAPImpl.java

Path: /Server/src/main/...

Location: Line 24

Type: Java Problem
```

I tried removing the dependency and add it again but without any luck.
Both projects do refer to JAVA 1.8.
Both projects have been build with targets clean an package multiple times.
Both projects have been updated by Righclick or pressing F5.
I am using Eclipse Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
I am using apache-maven-3.3.9
I am using m2e Plugin.

Any further help would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to make on command line: mvn clean package...

Comment: did not help but when I explicitly add this dependency within the Servers pom-file:

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

The error disappears. But I not really want to do that because this dependency still is defined within the server-base' pom-file and I added a dependency from server to server-base such that I expect to get all dependencies from server-base in transitive way. Am I wrong?

Comment: ok I think I got it
the dependecy I am talking about within server-base pom-file has got scope: provided, when erasing it (wich leads to use default) or changing it to 'compile' (which I think is the default) the error also disappears.
I now am going to research whether scope compile is ok with look to the deployment (I may do not want the jar being deployed also because the target application server still has its own jars for thi).
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to 'solve' this:

1)
explicitly add the required dependency within the server-projects pom-file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2)
change the scop of the required dependency within the server-base-projects pom file from up to now 'provide' to 'compile' or erase the scope tag at all such that the default scope is used by maven (which I guess is 'compile')

old:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

new:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
  <scope></scope>
</dependency>
```

or:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Some background to this from documentation:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies

> **provided** This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example,
>   when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you
>   would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs
>   to scope provided because the web container provides those classes.
>   This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath,
>   and is not transitive.

Thanks all.

Comment: In my case replacing the jar dependency with the maven one did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like apache logging library is not brought transitively from your `server-base` project. Check if in project `server` under MavenDependencies you see `commons-logging` (apache logging) jar. If not, then add this as your maven dependency in `server-base` project.

Repeat the above for all jars that `server-base` depends on.

Comment: I can see under servers maven dependencies:

jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final-redhat-1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar

As stated above this Logger-Object is the only one having problems.
If it wouldnt be there I think the server-project also should display an error within the class "BaseService".

Comment: I thought that your server-base being an ant based project would be using scope system in maven dependency.

Comment: all projects are build with maven